# fixed merge conflicts, then added, but still getting "unmerged files"

Tags: git

I have two branches, `master` and `side`.  I'm tracking file `somedoc.txt` in both branches.

Switched to `side` using:

```
git checkout side
```

Made a change to line 1 of `somedoc.txt`.

Committed my changes with:

```
git commit -a -m "made some changes"
```

Switched back to `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

Merged changes:

```
git merge side
```

Got the expected `Merge conflict in somedoc.txt`.

Edited `somedoc.txt` to resolve the `<<<<<< HEAD ... side >>>>>>` conflict.

Added `somedoc.txt` with:

```
git add somedoc.txt
```

Tried to commit with:

```
git commit
```

At this point I got the error:

```
error: 'commit' is not possible because you have unmerged files.
```

Running `git status` gives the following:

```
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   somedoc.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

When I go back in to edit `somedoc.txt` I don't see the conflict tags.  How do I resolve this?

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: @NathanDawson, ok that resolved it.  Not sure why but i was able to get to the commit message screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to finish the merge off. Once you've fixed any conflicts run `git commit -a`.

In response to your comment `git commit` on it's own wouldn't have worked. At that point you hadn't marked the file as resolved using `git add` which is why you were presented with an error. The `-a` switch will automatically add known files.